# OpenCV capture from USB not iSight (OSX)

Tags: macos, opencv, webcam, isight

I am having trouble accessing the external USB camera instead of the built-in iSight when using OpenCV with a MacBook Pro under Mac OSX.

When passing an argument to the `cvCaptureFromCAM(index)` function other than 0 or -1 I will always get a
`Warning: Max Camera Num is 0; Using camera 0`

The camera is a Sony PS3 EYE working perfectly with the macam driver and quicktime component.
Yet I am unable to access it using OpenCV which will always default to the built-in iSight (even when trying to "occupy" the iSight with a different program).

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance, your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was just messing with the same problem, macam drivers are 32 bit, if your opencv install is compiled as 64 bit it won't work. I end up installing opencv twice 64 bit with mac ports and 32 bit with howebrew whenever I am using ps3eye I switch to 32 bit version.