# Can't initialize ps3 eye on mac using opencv with python but c examples work fine

Tags: macos, opencv, python-2.7, webcam

I've installed OpenCV via macports by doing the following "port install opencv +python27". Using C and calling cvCaptureFromCAM(0) I can capture frames from the cam just fine. When I try it with python's cv.CaptureFromCAM(0) it dies with the following:

```
QTKit didn't find any attached Video Input Devices!
Warning, camera failed to properly initialize!
Cleaned up camera.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    temp=cv.CloneImage(frame)
```

Comment: just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041752/opencv-capture-from-usb-not-isight-osx . I'm going to try the 32 bit version via homebrew.

Answer (score -1):

With python you can try the **cv2** interface:

```
import cv2

# initiate the capture interface
cv2.VideoCapture() # that's right, no params
```